# Get unique values from a column of cells in excel and populate another column

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a column of anchor texts I use for link building. Some of them are duplicates.

How can I get the unique values of those anchor texts so I can populate another column only with the unique values?

In google spreadsheets I use the forumla `=UNIQUE(A1:A10)`

In SQL the formula is `SELECT DISTINCT anchortext FROM...`

How can I do it for Excel 2013 or erlier versions?

Comment: In Excel, a VBA macro is usually the easiest way to go.  For some ideas, look at Chip Pearsons [Distinct Values Function](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/DistinctValues.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the ["Remove Duplicates"](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Filter-for-unique-values-or-remove-duplicate-values-ccf664b0-81d6-449b-bbe1-8daaec1e83c2) option in the Data tab?

1.)  Select the range of cells, or make sure that the active cell is in a table.

2.)  On the Data tab, in the Data Tools group, click Remove Duplicates.

Do one or more of the following:
Under Columns, select one or more columns.
- To quickly select all columns, click Select All.
- To quickly clear all columns, click Unselect All.

3.)  If the range of cells or table contains many columns and you want to only select a few columns, you may find it easier to click Unselect All, and then under Columns, select those columns.

4.)  Click OK.

A message is displayed indicating how many duplicate values were removed and how many unique values remain, or if no duplicate values were removed.

5.)  Click OK.